# LG G4 Build.MANUFACTURER

Tags: android

Could someone please confirm what the value of `Build.MANUFACTURER` is on a `LG G4` device.

```
import android.os.Build;
Log.v("foobar", Build.MANUFACTURER);
```

I can't find the information anywhere...

Comment: Should just be `LG` or `LG Electronics`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the LG G4 that I have it's:
V/foobar: LGE